# Can I make my controller single threaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, puma

So recently I made a switch from WEBrick to Puma and some really strange stuff started happening in my application.

I discovered that an application is firing 3-4 create webhooks to my application in a short burst instead of just one. Despite checking for duplicates, they still occur in my application. After switching to single thread this problem no longer occurs, but my application is a lot slower.

Is it possible to make specific parts of code (or this specific controller) run on a single thread?

Comment: the create action is being called multiple times ?

Comment: Yes, it is a shopify webhook that sends over an order to my application. I create the order and immediately reply with a 200 ok, and do the rest of the processing with a delayed job. The delayed job is being called multiple times causing a lot of issues.

Comment: If there are multiple delayed job entries because the create action is called multiple times then maybe you can disable the submit button on a create and then enable it back when needed.

Comment: The controller is invoked by Shopify when it sends webhooks to my application. Unfortunately a bug in Shopify is causing it to trigger multiple times for the same event. So unfortunately there is no button to disable

Comment: This might help -  https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/order-payment-webhook-sends-messages-multiple-times-within-quick-succession-138875